# Possible to Read Excel Tab into Code and Write Back that Same Tab With Formatting

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl, xlsxwriter, styleframe

I have code that creates an excel file named `file_A` using XlsxWriter.  Users have sent me an excel file named `file_b` which just has one tab, named `tab_b`.  They want `tab_b` appended to `file_A`.  This `tab_b` includes a lot of formatting (some of it I believe falls under "rich" formatting") that I would rather not have to hardcode into the code base.

Is there a way to upload `tab_b` into the code base as some kind of tab object?  Then, I could append this tab to `file_A`, and all formatting and hardcoding would be encapsulated in the tab object.

We're already using XlsxWriter and openpyxl in our code base, but I don't know if either were really made to do this sort of thing.  I'm open to other modules if necessary, but it does have to be Python compatible.

Example code of how we currently create `file_A` looks like this:

```
writer = pd.ExcelWriter(output_file_path, engine='xlsxwriter')
someDataFrame.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='PreExisting_Tab')
writer.save()
```

Ideally, what I'm hoping to find out, is if there is real code for the following pseudocode below:

```
writer = pd.ExcelWriter(output_file_path, engine='xlsxwriter')
someDataFrame.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='PreExisting_Tab')

tab_b = readTabWithFormattingIntoPython("filePathToFile_B")
tab_b.to_Excel(writer,sheet_name='tab_b')

writer.save()
```

This screen shot below depicts tab_b inside of file_b.
[image: A screenshot of a mockup of the excel tab they want appended is pictured here:]

**UPDATE** Thank you @DeepSpace for bringing StyleFrame to my attention.  It looks promising, but my initial attempt at proof of concept failed.  Here is what I tried (it seems similar enough to the code in your example, not sure why it's failing):

```
    from StyleFrame import StyleFrame
    writer = pd.ExcelWriter(output_file_path, engine='openpyxl')

    tab_to_convert= StyleFrame.read_excel(file_B_file_path, read_style=True)

    tab_to_convert.to_excel(writer)
    writer.save()
```

The result of the code above is that an excel file gets created with one sheet that has no data or formatting from the file it was supposed to have read.  Within cell A1, it says "This sheet contains FactSet XML data for use with this workbook's =FDS codes. Modifying the worksheet's contents may damage the wrokbook's = FDS functionality."

Not sure if this is why it's not working, but I had to specify, when creating the writer, "engine='openpyxl'".  If I didn't specify that, it tried to use XlsxWriter and failed due to AttributeError: 'Workbook' object has no attribute 'get_sheet_by_name'

**2ND UPDATE**  StyleFrame ended up working.  See comments below in @DeepSpace's answer.

Comment: To be honest. If you want this kind of control, you should work directly with openpyxl. It has a utility for converting dataframes to rows and will let you work directly with existing Excel files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[StyleFrame](https://styleframe.readthedocs.io) (which, as a disclaimer, I'm one of the authors of) can do that.

```
from StyleFrame import StyleFrame

writer = pd.ExcelWriter(output_file_path)
someDataFrame.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='PreExisting_Tab')

tab_b = StyleFrame.read_excel("filePathToFile_B", read_style=True)
tab_b.to_Excel(writer, sheet_name='tab_b')

writer.save()
```

Comment: sorry but this ended up not working for me.  Just as a proof of concept, my first attempt was just to read in one excel sheet as a StyleFrame.  Then immediately convert that back into an excel sheet and save the writer.  This resulted in an excel sheet with none of my formatting or data.  The output excel sheet just said, in cell A1, "This sheet contains FactSet XML data for use with this workbook's =FDS codes.  Modifying the worksheet's contents may damage the wrokbook's = FDS functionality."  Do you know how to address that?

Comment: I added code to the bottom of my question with my attempt at replicating your answer

Comment: @Curiosity It seems like it's some macro-level "protection" on the XLSX file itself. Does it work if you only use pandas to read and save the file?

Comment: That was the issue!  Thank you @DeepSpace.

Answer (score 1):

With regards to the *"This sheet contains FactSet XML data for use with this workbook's =FDS codes. Modifying the worksheet's contents may damage the workbook's = FDS functionality."* error, this is caused by a very hidden sheet that was added by the excel FactSet plugin. You can view the very hidden sheet if you open the file in excel and then go to VBA. In the project overview you will see a file called __FDSCACHE__. You can either delete this sheet or explicitly define which sheet you want to open, for example

```
df = pd.read_excel("foo.xlsx", sheet_name='Sheet1')
```

Comment: This solved the FactSet error message for me, thank you!